# Quick CSS Question

Tags: css

Can I apply a stroke on all JPEG images and not include other image types like PNG, using a css stylesheet. How would I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
img[src$='.jpg'] {
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Give all JPEG images a class like `class="jpeg"` and apply the style to the class.

Comment: I would have to go in and manually add that to each jpeg? I have a ton of jpeg's already so that would be very time consuming.. any other ways?

Comment: Just do a find and replace. Find `.jpg"` and replace with `.jpg" class="jpeg"`.

Answer (score 1):

If adding a class is not an option, you can also try:

```
img[src$=".jpg"], img[src$=".jpeg"] {
  /* do whatever you need to here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: There is no reliable way with CSS alone.

Long answer: You can use the `[attribute$='end of value']` way (`img[src$='jpg'],img[src$='jpeg'] { /* CSS properties*/ }`), but it's CSS 3 and not supported correctly in most browsers.

Workarounds could vary. You can apply a class to those as tskuzzy answered. I assume you are trying to avoid this kind of "apply manually to every image" way, so, I'd say use JavaScript to do it. This selector although won't work in CSS, will do work in jQuery for example, even in IE6 (with different slowness across browsers, but usable).

Something like

**jQuery:**

```
$("img[src$='jpg'],img[src$='jpeg']").addClass("jpeg");
```

**CSS:**

```
img.jpeg { /* style here */ }
```

Comment: Your short and long answered contradicted each other. Made an edit to amend that.

Comment: Updated with different words. Check it now.

Comment: I made a further change. They actually have great support.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply stroke on all jpg and jpeg in your page. You should to try CSS attribute selector like this.

img[src$=".jpg"], img[src$=".jpeg"] {

border:1px solid #000;

}